# The method mergeList(List<Integer>) in the type Utility<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Number>)

Tags: java

I have this assignment where I'm only allowed to change the signature of the methods. I have a class utility and a test class. Th issue I'm having is that i keep getting argument errors. Here is the Utility Class

```
public class Utility <T extends Comparable<T>> {  //Change this line to create a parameterized class
    
    // Insert your code here
    public ArrayList<T> list;
    
    public Utility() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    
    public Utility (List<T> list) { 
        this.list = (ArrayList<T>) new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    public void mergeList(List<T> list) { //This is the method that the error refers to
        for (T obj: this.list)
            list.add(obj);
    }
}
```

This is the test that keeps giving me errors

```
void testMergeList2() {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        myList.add(0); 
        myList.add(1); 
        myList.add(2); 
        myList.add(3); 
        Utility<Integer> ut = new Utility<Integer>(myList); 

        List<Number> myList2 = new ArrayList<Number>(); 
        myList2.add(0); 
        myList2.add(1); 
        myList2.add(2); 
        myList2.add(5); 
        ut.mergeList(myList2);      //This is where I get the error 
        boolean actual = true;
        for (int i= 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if ((Integer) myList2.get(i) != i || (Integer)myList2.get(i+4)!= i) {
                actual = false; 
                break; 
            }
        }

        boolean expected = false; 
        assertEquals(expected, actual, "mergeList Failed! " + expected + " expected but "+ actual + " is given");
        
        
    }
```

I tried changing T for something else but then the compiler tells me to cast T which I'm not allowed to do since I can't change the body of the method.

Comment: Please include the StackTrace you are getting. It will help determine where the issue is.

Comment: How do I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Utility is declared using `Integer` however the `myList2` is using `Number`. Those are incompatible types.

In order to fix this, change `mergeList(List<T> list)` to just `mergeList(List list)`. This will work and your test will pass.

Comment: This test was provided by my instructor so i can't change it, is there a way that by changing the method it can accept both?

Comment: You can remove the generic from the `mergeList(List list)`. Then the test will pass